# Getting all pixel values(rgba)

Tags: image, go

I'm new at Go and trying to improve my skills. Currently I'm working with images and I need to have all pixels' red value of an image. I know I can use the code below to achieve this but it seemed slow to me(~485 msecs),

```
pixList := make([]uint8, width*height)

for y := 0; y < height; y++ {
    for x := 0; x < width; x++ {
        r, _, _, _ := img.At(x, y).RGBA()
        var rNew uint8 = uint8(float32(r)*(255.0/65535.0))
        pixList[(x*height)+y] = rNew
    }
}
```

Is there any faster way to do this? Any built-in functions to get all pixel values at once?

Edit: I'm now using the Pix to get all pixel data but still my Pix list is not giving what I'm looking for.

new code:

```
pixList := img.(*image.Paletted).Pix
newPixList := make([]uint8, width*height)

fmt.Println(len(pixList))//gives width*height, shouldn't it be width*height*4?
for index := 0; index < width*height; index++ {
    newPixList[index] = pixList[index*4]//this part gives index out of range error, because the pixList is length of width*height, i dunno why

}
```

I think it's not behaving my image as it's an rgba image, maybe a conversion could work. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: You could multi-thread it: have several go routines work on different chunks of the image at once.

Comment: You don't need any methods, every image is has a Pix slice containing all the pixel values.

Comment: @JimB since I'm new, I don't know how to use it. Can u provide an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't make this pattern performant, because this requires an interface method call for every pixel. For fast access to the image data, you access the image's data directly. Take the `image.RGBA` type for example:

```
type RGBA struct {
        // Pix holds the image's pixels, in R, G, B, A order. The pixel at
        // (x, y) starts at Pix[(y-Rect.Min.Y)*Stride + (x-Rect.Min.X)*4].
        Pix []uint8
        // Stride is the Pix stride (in bytes) between vertically adjacent pixels.
        Stride int
        // Rect is the image's bounds.
        Rect Rectangle
}
```

The docs for each image type include the data layout and indexing formula. For this type you could extract all red pixels from the `Pix` slice with:

```
w, h := img.Rect.Dx(), img.Rect.Dy()
pixList := make([]uint8, w*h)

for i := 0; i < w*h; i++ {
    pixList[i] = img.Pix[i*4]
}
```

If you need to convert other image types, you can use the existing methods to do the color conversion, but first assert the correct image type and use the native `*At` method to avoid the interface call. Extracting the approximate red values from a YCbCr image :

```
w, h := img.Rect.Dx(), img.Rect.Dy()
pixList := make([]uint8, w*h)

for x := 0; x < w; x++ {
    for y := 0; y < h; y++ {
        r, _, _, _ := img.YCbCrAt(x, y).RGBA()
        pixList[(x*h)+y] = uint8(r >> 8)

    }
}
return pixList
```

Similar to how the YCbCr image above has no "red" pixels (the value needs to be computed for each individual pixel), a paletted image has no individual RGBA values for the pixels, and needs to be looked up in the image's palette. You could take this one step further and predetermine the color model of the palette colors to remove the `Color.RGBA()` interface call to speed this up even more like so:

```
palette := make([]*color.RGBA, len(img.Palette))
for i, c := range img.Palette {
    palette[i] = c.(*color.RGBA)
}

pixList := make([]uint8, len(img.Pix))

for i, p := range img.Pix {
    pixList[i] = palette[p].R
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for detailed answer, I only could have pixlist like this `pixList := img.(*image.Paletted).Pix` because the one you provided raised the error of `img.Pix undefined (type image.Image has no field or method Pix)`. Yet, my pixlist is not giving right values(since I have a working Python implementation, I know they are wrong), I updated the question with new code. Any ideas?

Comment: @paradoksumsu: If you're working with a paletted image, there are no "red" pixels -- you have to lookup the color in the image palette.

Comment: I understand this but I'm not sure if I understood the problem correctly. I'm able to get r values with Python. Why Go cannot take it? This is a png image after all, shouldn't it have all rgba values?

Comment: @paradoksumsu: You can get the RGBA values the way you were getting them, but you asked for a faster way. If you want to avoid the overhead of the interfaces and implicit conversions, you need to handle the image data directly. I don't know what you're doing in python, but it is doing the conversion for you at some point, possibly normalizing the images to RGBA during "decoding".

Comment: @paradoksumsu: I figured I would update the answer to show the direct use of the palette color.Color if you're interested.